# Does react native include a source map in the build

Tags: react-native, source-maps

When building the APK and IPA apps with react native, the JS bundle is included inside the apps but does RN also include a source map inside the apps ? If yes, then how to disable this behavior ?

Comment: Not unless you configure it to

Comment: Does this answer your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960891/what-is-react-natives-bundle-and-its-purpose#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20bundle%20is%20indeed%20'the,the%20code%20on%20the%20fly.)?